# Does GAE GCS write have asynchronous version like the NDB functions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, asynchronous, google-cloud-storage

Does [GAE GCS write](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions) have asynchronous version like the NDB functions(eg, put_async)?

I found out(from appstats) that since I am uploading multiple files sequentially in my code, it is consuming a lot a time(all of them being sequential). I am trying to reduce this time since with six files it is ~7 seconds and I wish to have more files.

I have put the following code snippet in a for loop which iterates over all the files selected by the user on the webpage:

```
gcs_file = gcs.open (filename, 'w', content_type = 'image/jpeg') 
gcs_file.write (photo) 
gcs_file.close ()
```

Please let me know if you need any more data

**UPDATE**
Original code:

```
photo_blobkey_list = []             
video_blobkey_list = [] 

i = 0 
for photo in photo_list: 
    filename = bucket + "/user_pic_"+str (user_index) + "_" + str (i) 
    # Store the file in GCS 
    gcs_file = gcs.open (filename, 'w', content_type = 'image/jpeg') 
    gcs_file.write (photo) 
    gcs_file.close () 
    # Store the GCS filename in Blobstore 
    blobstore_filename = '/gs' + filename 
    photo_blobkey = blobstore.create_gs_key (blobstore_filename) 
    photo_blobkey_list.append (photo_blobkey) 
    i = i + 1 

i = 0 
for video in video_list: 
    filename = bucket + "/user_video_"+str (user_index) + "_" + str (i) 
    filename = filename.replace (" ", "_") 
    # Store the file in GCS 
    gcs_file = gcs.open (filename, 'w', content_type = 'video/avi') 
    gcs_file.write (video) 
    gcs_file.close () 
    # Store the GCS filename in Blobstore 
    blobstore_filename = '/gs' + filename 
    video_blobkey = blobstore.create_gs_key (blobstore_filename) 
    video_blobkey_list.append (video_blobkey) 
    i = i + 1 
:: 
user_record.put ()
```

**My Doubt:**
Based on the suggestions, I plan to put the GCS write part in a tasklet subroutine which takes filename and the photo/video as argument. How do I use "yield" here so as to make the above code run in parallel as much as possible(all the photo and video write operations)? As per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async?csw=1#parallel_queries_yield), I need to provide all the arguments to yield so as to make the tasklets run in parallel. But, in my case, the number of photos and videos uploaded is variable number.

Relevant [official docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async?csw=1#parallel_queries_yield) text:

> If that were two separate yield statements, they would happen in
>   series. But yielding a tuple of tasklets is a parallel yield: the
>   tasklets can run in parallel and the yield waits for all of them to
>   finish and returns the results.

Comment: I think you will find that you could wrap this in tasklets and get async behaviour.  Either as a simple tasklet (because gcs would use urlfetch under the hood) or use the @ndb.synctasklet .  Have a read of the later sections of the ndb async docs - (it has uses for non ndb async api's)  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async?csw=1

Comment: @TimHoffman Thanks for your reply. I would try using the tasklet and update you

Comment: @TimHoffman I have updated my question with more data. As suggested by you and marcadian, I plan to use tasklets. I have certain basic doubts on how to implement it which I have put in my post. Please help clarify them

Comment: Placing gcs calls in a `@ndb.tasklet` is a *bad idea* on production due to deadlock (hard to reproduce on `dev_appserver.py`).

We need a means to yield all GCS calls with RPCs. :3

Comment: @gsinha are you uploading this from the frontend?

Comment: @RafaelBarros Yes, in the sense that it is a user facing request operation. A user selects the files to upload on the website and hits the "Submit" button. The request (all form data including the files) is processed by the backend GAE Python code. This Python code finishes storing the data and uploading the files to GCS and returns a response to the user.

Comment: In that case I strongly recommend not sending things to back end app, and instead, creating an upload url with blob storage and using that on a form or ajax upload.

Comment: @RafaelBarros Thanks for your feedback but why do you think it is better to switch over to blobstore instead of writing to GCS ?

Comment: Well, you will still be able to store your files in gcs, but you just won't have to write them from the python app. You can tell blobstore to create the upload URL for gcs, and the front end uses Google infrastructure instead of yours. (I'm on my phone i can't give you a better answer now, sorry)

Comment: @RafaelBarros Sorry but I did not get you completely. Please provide a more elaborate answer whenever you get time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @gsinha see the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823206/upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-from-appengine-app

Answer (score 3):

You can do the write operation in a task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would try out [task](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async?csw=1) and update my post

Comment: Keep in mind that task has 100k payload limit (for push taskqueue), if your object is larger than that. You can put the object in datastore and passed in the key to the task

Comment: I have updated my question with more data. As suggested by you and Tim Hoffman, I plan to use tasklets. I have certain basic doubts on how to implement it which I have put in my post. Please help clarify them

Answer (score 2):

There's async versions of the [URLFetch API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/).

You could use this to write async direct to cloud storage using the cloud storage [XML](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api-overview) or [JSON](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) API's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution looks good but since I have already used the gcs library in the manner shown above, my first choice would be for something with that(instead of migrating to JSON or XML form). If I do not find a good solution with the present one, I would go for your solution

Comment: Side note - if you do it that way, you'll get charged for all of the outbound transfer costs (as opposed to using the GCS library, which would be free).

Comment: @JeffTratner no you wont

Comment: @StuartLangley that's what Google Support told me last week; it'd be great if that were not the case.

Comment: @JeffTratner who in support told you that?

Comment: @StuartLangley given that you work on App Engine, I'm guessing I was told the wrong information. I was told by Enterprise Support that using the URLFetch or Sockets API incurred costs, whereas the GCS library somehow didn't incur charges because it was able to take advantage of Google Cloud <-> Google Cloud pricing. Didn't make complete sense to me that the GCS library could somehow avoid using those APIs, but that's what I was told. If you want more details, can we continue this over email or something?

Comment: @JeffTratner sure ping me offline if you like